# install.packages() failing due to lack of memory?

Tags: r, ubuntu, vps, install.packages

I have a VPS with Ramnode with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I have their low memory plan (128mb). I have successfully installed R, but I cannot install any packages from CRAN. This is the result:

```
> install.packages("Rccp",repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Killed
```

And then R is exited automatically. The same happens regardless of which package I try to install. My memory usage is maxed while the installation is in progress, so I imagine that is where the problem is.

In anticipation of this answer, I want to say that I know a simple solution is to purchase a VPS with more memory, but I am looking for a workaround for the package install. For my purposes, R works fine with 128mb memory except for the package installation. I don't want to pay 2x (or more) what I am paying now just so that I can install the packages I need, because after this installation I won't need that extra memory again.

Comment: have you tried compiling from source?

Comment: Do you mean package `Rcpp`?

Comment: If you install the packages on a local machine running the same system and R version, you could simply upload your library to the remote server

Comment: I have no experience of using R on a VPS, but is it possible you need to run as root with something like `sudo R` to download files or add to /usr ? Are you able to write a file from R to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library? Does changing the folder to save packages to solve the problem (maybe to somewhere in /home)?

Comment: Similar to @ping's answer, try setting your library path to somewhere you *know* you have write access to, with something like: `.libPaths(c('/home/you/.Rlibrary', .libPaths()))` (after having created the appropriate directory, of course). After this, try again to install the package.

Comment: I did try installing from source, same problem. I did mean Rcpp, that was a typo. Permissions are not an issue here. I did run it with sudo. Plus, I am running as root anyway. It doesn't work regardless of the directory I'm in.  @Dominic Comtois I will try that!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the same problem on an AWS micro instance. I suspect memory is the culprit as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @BruceAlderman Memory was the problem, but I didn't find a work around. It only worked once I paid up and upgraded the memory available to my VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only fix was to indeed pony up and upgrade the memory available to my VPS. There was no workaround. I did this and was able to install the packages successfully.